# Problem with $ source torsocks off

Tags: bash, tor

(edit: Ubuntu 20)

I installed TOR and then "torified" my shell with:

```
$ echo ". torsocks on" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then, not related, I ran into some issues with TOR and had to purge remove everything. But, before I did, I ran:

```
$ source torsocks off
```

It said it shut off. But, now, everytime I open a terminal I get:

```
bash: torsocks: No such file or directory
```

at every startup. If I try to turn torsocks off, of course I get:

```
bash: torsocks: No such file or directory
```

How do I undo this? I have no idea.

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
# GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 using VTE 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To undo

```
$ echo ". torsocks on" >> ~/.bashrc
```

you can open the file in a text editor

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and either remove or comment out (using `#`) the offending line

```
# . torsocks on
```

Comment: Did it! Thank You!
Of Course! I feel dumb now. Well, it's fixed anyway!

Comment: @VíðarrKerr If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: OK, I forgot. Thanks!